# Prime divisors of $a^n+b$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b\in \mathbb N$, $a>1$. Prove that the set $M=\{\omega(a^n+b)\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is infinite, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct pime divisors of $n$.

First, obviously we have to prove that $P=\{p\in \mathbb P:\exists n\in \mathbb N \text{ s.t. } p\mid a^n+b\}$ is infinite, but since the set of prime divisors of $a^n$ is finite, we have by Kobayashi that $P$ is infinite (If somebody knows how to prove this without Kobayashi feel free to post the proof).

So I only managed to solve the case $(a,b)=1$. Here's the proof,

Fist denote $f(n)=a^n+b$. Assume $M$ is finite and take $m=\max M$ then there would be some $n$ such that $$f(n)=a^n+b=\prod_{i=1}^m{p_i^{c_i}}$$
Consider the number $m=n+\prod\phi(p_i^{c_i+1})$, by Fermat we have $\forall 1\le i\le m$, $$f(m)\equiv a^n+b\equiv f(n)\pmod{p_i^{c_i+1}}$$
So $p_i^{c_i+1}\mid f(m)\iff p_i^{c_i+1}\mid f(n)$ this is enough to imply $$\nu_{p_i}(f(m))=\nu_{p_i}(f(n))$$
But $f(m)>f(n)$ so there must be some $p\ne p_i$ such that $p\mid f(m)$ contradicting the maximality of $m$. There are two main problems when $(a,b)>1$, the first is you can't directly use Fermat's Theorem and the second is how do you ensure that $\nu_p(f(m))=\nu_p(f(n))$ for $p\mid (a,b)$? Certainly you can't use Fermat there.

Comment: You can reduce it to the case about $ca^n+b$ where $(ac,b)=1$ and you might be able to do your same trick from your first answer from there.

Comment: So if you start with $(a,b)=(6,4),$ you change the problem to be about $(a,c,b)=(6,9,1).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can change your proof to prove that if $a,b,c$ are integers with $\gcd(ac,b)=1,$ then the set of values $S_{a,b,c}=\{\omega(ca^n+b)\}$ is infinite.

Now, if you let $(b_0,c_0)=(b,1).$ If $\gcd(a,b_k)=1,$ we stop.

Otherwise, we let $$c_{k+1}=\frac{ac_k}{\gcd(a,b_k)}\\b_{k+1}=\frac{b_k}{\gcd(a,b_k)}.$$

We can prove by induction that for all $n,$ $\gcd(b_{k+1},c_{k+1})=1.$ We also see that $b_k$ is strictly decreasing and positive, so eventually, we must stop.

But $S_{a,b_{k+1},c_{l+1}}$ is infinite iff $S_{a,b_k,c_k}$ is infinite.

You original question is whether $S_{a,b_0,c_0}$ was infinite.

Comment: I didn't understand Can you do an example like $12^n+6$?

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(12,1,2).$ @PNT $(b_0,c_0)=(6,1),$ then $b_1=6/\gcd(12,6)=1, c_1=c_0a/\gcd(12,6)=2.$

Comment: No like the process you mentioned $c_{k+1}$ and $b_{k+1}$.

Comment: Already updated my comment. It is just one step. @PNT

Comment: Another way to phrase it is, without the induction, is, if $\nu_p(b)=b_p$ and $\nu_p(a)=a_p$ we can define $k=\max_{p\mid(a,b)} \lceil b_p/a_p\rceil$ and let $$c=a^k/\gcd(a^k,b), b'=b/\gcd(a^k,b).$$

Comment: Basically, $k$ is the smallest integer such that $\nu_p(b)\leq \nu_p(a^k)$ for all primes $p\mid(a,b).$

Comment: The key is $$\omega(2\cdot12^n+1)\leq \omega(12^{n+1}+6)\leq 2+ \omega(2\cdot12^n+1),$$ and the sets being infinite is the same as the sets being unbounded.

Comment: By "Without induction" you mean you can it in one step?

Comment: Well, there's always implicit induction. I meant, the second version doesn't require the inductive definition of $(b_{k+1},c_{k+1}).$ But it is essentially the same process.

Comment: Another example is $(a,b)=(12,40).$ Then $k=2$ and $c=144/\gcd(144,40)=18, b'=40/\gcd(144,40)=5.$ We then have: $$\omega(18\cdot 12^n+5)\leq \omega(12^{n+2}+40)\leq 1+\omega(18\cdot 12^n+5)$$

Comment: In general, you'll have: $$\omega(ca^n+b')\leq \omega(a^{n+k}+b)=\omega(\gcd(a,b))+\omega(ca^n+b')$$